# Fundamental domain of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ acted on by $\operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb Z)$

Tags: matrices, reference-request, lie-groups, lattices-in-lie-groups

What is a simple description of a fundamental domain of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ acted on by $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$?

$\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ is the group of all real invertible matrices with matrix multiplication, $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$ the group of all matrices with integer entries, whose inverses also have integer entries, with matrix multiplication. $h \in \operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb Z) \subset \operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ acts on $g \in \operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ by letting $h\cdot g := hg$

Remarks:

A fundamental domain $F$ is a subset of $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ such that for any $x$ in $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ there is exactly one $h$ in $\operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb Z)$ such that $hx \in F$. I'm looking for an as clean as possible description of some $F$ in terms of the matrix entries. Clearly $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ can be replaced with any set of (possibly not invertible) matrices with $n$ rows (possibly with few or more than n columns). The case with one column and $n=2$ is not too different from finding a fundamental domain of the upper half plane with respect to Möbius transformations. Also, $\operatorname{GL}$ could have been replaced with $\operatorname{SL}$.

This appears as a very basic question to me, and if it turns out I'm ignorant of some useful tools or theorems I will accept pointers to such. In fact this would be even better than a direct answer to the specific question (since I have many related seemingly basic questions), as long as it helps significantly in answering the specific question.

Comment: You may wish to consult Dave Witte Morris's pre-book on [Arithmetic groups](http://people.uleth.ca/~dave.morris/books/IntroArithGroups.html), especially chapter 7 where he constructs a fundamental domain for $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb Z)$ via Siegel sets (generalizing the classical case $n=2$ rather directly). In our research group we had a seminar on an earlier version about 10 years ago and it was already quite good at that point. I'm sure the quality hasn't decreased...

Comment: @all: concerning the (lattices-in-lie-groups) tag, I was unsure how to tag this, so I decided to create this one (even if it's not a perfect fit here). Feel free to remove it or replace it if you can think of a better one -- I was even less happy with (arithmetic-groups) due to the possible confusion with $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$, say.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm working on some old recollections here of how to do things, so take it with a grain of salt.

First off, we tend to mod out by the maximal compact subgroup on the other side (so we get the symmetric space).
So really you want to be working with something like $\mathbb{SO}(n, \mathbb{R}) \backslash \mathbb{SL(n,\mathbb{R})} / \mathbb{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$. Except there's an overall scaling factor of $\mathbb{R}^* / \mathbb{Q}^*$ since $\mathbb{GL}(\mathbb{Z})$ has rational determinants, while $\mathbb{GL}(\mathbb{R})$ doesn't.

In the case $n=2$, you can think of this as rotating and rescaling a fundamental parallelogram of the lattice so that one vector is $\hat{x}$, while the second vector lies in a fundamental domain of $H / \mathbb{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

In the case of higher $n$, you're going to do the same thing -- rotate so that the first vector is $e_1$, the second vector lies in the $(e_1, e_2)$ plane, etc.  So think of it as an upper-triangular matrix with positive entries along the diagonal and a 1 in the upper-left corner.  You can furthermore arrange things so that each row vector is longer than the one below it ($|\vec{v_i}| \geq |\vec{v_j}|, i<j$). Now, further constraints from the $\mathbb{SL}(\mathbb{Z})$ factor: You can either fix $|a_{ij}| \leq |a_{jj}|/2$ or you can fix $|\vec{v_i}| <= |\vec{v_i} + n * \vec{v_j}| \Leftrightarrow \vec{v_i} \cdot \vec{v_j} \leq |\vec{v_j}|^2$, for $i < j$.

That takes care of (some of) the upper-triangular portion of $\mathbb{SL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$, as well as the $S_n$ subgroup.  The rest of it is much trickier, specifically the generators which act like $z \rightarrow -1/z$ in the $\mathbb{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$ context.